# Parsing XML using JQuery, need to find by attribute name

Tags: jquery, html, xml

I am trying to parse some XML data to display in a basic web page. The XML is the following:

```
    <response> 
  <variable name = "Input1">False</variable> 
  <variable name = "Input2">False</variable> 
  <variable name = "Input3">False</variable> 
  <variable name = "Input4">False</variable> 
  <variable name = "Input5">False</variable> 
  <variable name = "Input6">False</variable> 
  <variable name = "Input7">False</variable> 
  <variable name = "Input8">False</variable> 
</response>
```

I have some code which is display that but currently I get all 8 variables show in 1 text area.

```
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            //To change controller, please chnage the IP below.
            url: "http://172.20.2.17/query/variable?Input1&Input2&Input3&Input4&Input5&Input6&Input7&Input8",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: parseSystem

          });
        })      
        //Parse System XML Response 
        function parseSystem(xml)
{

  $(xml).find("response").each(function()
   {    

        $("#Input1").append($(this).find("variable").text())
    $("#Input2").append($(this).find("variable").text())
    $("#Input3").append($(this).find("variable").text())
    $("#Input4").append($(this).find("variable").text())
    $("#Input5").append($(this).find("variable").text())
    $("#Input6").append($(this).find("variable").text())
    $("#Input7").append($(this).find("variable").text())
    $("#Input8").append($(this).find("variable").text())
   });
```

What I would is that Input1 in the XML is linked to #Input1 in the HTML and so forth.

Thank you for your time, it is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(xml).find("response").each(function()
   {    

    $("#Input1").append($(this).find("variable[name=Input1]").text())
    $("#Input2").append($(this).find("variable[name=Input2]").text())
    $("#Input3").append($(this).find("variable[name=Input3]").text())
    $("#Input4").append($(this).find("variable[name=Input4]").text())
    $("#Input5").append($(this).find("variable[name=Input5]").text())
    $("#Input6").append($(this).find("variable[name=Input6]").text())
    $("#Input7").append($(this).find("variable[name=Input7]").text())
    $("#Input8").append($(this).find("variable[name=Input8]").text())
   });
```

but there is a more flexible function:

```
$(xml).find("response").each(function(){
     $(this).find("variable").each(function(){
          var id = $(this).attr("name");
          $("#"+id).append($(this).text())
     });
});
```

Comment: you may reuse `$(this)` and not execute it twice :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(xml).find('response').each(function (index, element) {
    var $element = $(element);
    var $variables = $('variable', $element);
    $variables.each(function (index, variable) {
        var $variable = $(variable);
        var controlId = $variable.attr('name');
        var text = $variable.text();
        var $control = $('#' + controlId);
        $control.append(text);
    });
});
```